# Kernel source downloaded accidentally, and I want to delete it

Tags: apt, kernel, source

Didn't see a solved thread before asking this, but if I'm stupid, pls point me to the one.

So by accidentally I mean it was not what I expected it to download. I managed to setup closed NVIDIA driver with Secure Boot on, but the latest source I could find was 4.15.13 (if there's newer, I would appreciate if somebody linked me the one) (actually header from /usr/src was enough to set it up, but still, 4.15.13 was the latest I could find). I executed

```
sudo apt source linux-source
```

and others, and now this is how my Home looks like:

[image]

This invokes me to delete all of these by hand (y'know, sudo rm), but I just thought if it was downloaded from apt, then these must be the similar automatic way to get rid of it too?

I would appreciate any help sharing info, it is my first month to face Linux as a whole, but it's fun, ain't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see with command `man apt-get`:

```
Note that source packages are not installed and tracked in the dpkg
database like binary packages; they are simply downloaded to the
current directory, like source tarballs.
```

There is no other way to remove sources than by hand.

Comment: Quite a simple response, thanks! Could you point if Home is the only place these files can be?

Comment: @xt1zer drop then where ever you like just run that command the the intended directory

Answer (score 1):

I believe source files are just source files and used to build and install their respective apps, and these source files are then removed via the `rm` command. So in that case a simple delete will not hurt your system.

Comment: with apt-get source, apt-get fetches source packages to your working directory, they are not installed.

Comment: I know that updated my answer to reflect that!